# GIMP 2.10.20 snap install has no icons in the menus

Tags: icons, snap, menu, gimp

I have just recently installed Ubuntu 20.04, and soon after installed the GIMP 2.10.20 snap package. I noticed that almost all of the dropdown menus and context menus had no icons next to them, unlike the Windows 10 version. Having the icons next to the menus makes for a very quick visual reference when selecting menu items. Attached are screenshots from Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 showing the differences in the menus.

Ubuntu 20.04 GIMP 2.10.20 snap, missing menu icons:

[image: Ubuntu 20.04 GIMP 2.10.20 snap Missing menu icons]

Windows 10 64-bit - GIMP 2.10.14 menu icons:

[image: Windows 10 64-bit - GIMP 2.10.14 menu icons]

Comment: Did you try to change Theme or Icon Theme at Edit/Preferences/Interface?

Comment: I can confirm that not only snap, but also a regular .deb version of GIMP doesn't have those icons. But did GIMP in Ubuntu ever have them, anytime? I never saw Windows version of GIMP and wasn't aware that it has those icons, but I remember using a quite old version of GIMP in Ubuntu several years ago and if I remember correctly there were no icons in the menus back then, so I was not expecting them at all...

Comment: @raj to the best of my knowledge gimp never did have icons on the menu in Ubuntu going back to at least Ubuntu 12.04 LTS